# Open New Row of Tabs when selecting the ActionBar Tab

Tags: android, tabs

I have a requirement like below. When Selecting the Tab1, The New row of tabs(SUBTAB1,SUBTAB2,SUBTAB3) should appear and the corresponding information belongs to the SUBTABs should appear.

[image]

Comment: and what you have tried ? that's really easy stuff, first try, then come up with lil code, programming stuff !

Comment: I implemented the tabs (TAB1,TAB2,TAB3) using the ActionBar Tab. and displayed all of the information related to subtabs in a single fragment. But I want to categorize the informations in fragment using subtabs.I dont know how to make it.

Comment: use fragments inside fragments :/

Comment: Thanks for our answer.I will try as You said